# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when calling a function

Tags: javascript

I am using following code:

```
function getData2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sellSnet").value;
  var p = x * 0.1;
  var c = x - p;
  document.getElementById("agireceive").innerHTML = c;
};
```

and html is this

```
<input type="number" id="sellSnet" class="form-control" oninput="getData2()">
```

which gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>           at getData2 (exchange.js:151)
>           at HTMLInputElement.oninput (VM18589 :399)

now the funny thing is I use the exact same function further up in my code
Working code:

```
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var b = a * 0.1;
  var c = a - b;
  document.getElementById("receive").innerHTML = c;
};

<input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control" value="" oninput="getData();">
```

which wrks without a problem, so what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any element in your HTML with the id `agireceive`?

Comment: yes.  <input type="number" id="agireceive" class="form-control" >

Comment: Add html of *agireceive*.

Comment: I would assume that `#receive` is not an `<input>`. `.innerHTML` only applies to elements with an end tag. `<input>` does not have an end tag (ie void element) therefore does not contain HTML If you want to apply that `c` to `#agireceive` use the `.value` property instead.

Comment: @zer00ne i had to change the input tag to a p tag and now it works, thanks

Comment: @redbulll no problem, but a more semantic tag would be `<output></output>` which can accept `.innerHTML` or `.value`

Comment: great i used output now, seems to be a better fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML DOM innerHTML property is for changing the html content for the element. In your case you have input element which display the text using value attribute. so you should use that attribute to set the value.

```
 function getData2() {
        console.log("some");
        var x = document.getElementById("sellSnet").value;
        var p = x * 0.1;
        var c = x - p;
        document.getElementById("agireceive").value = c;
    }


    <input type="number" id="sellSnet" class="form-control" oninput="getData2()">
    <input type="number" id="agireceive" class="form-control" >
```

Answer (score 0):

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

This error is thrown when the target element is not available at the time of execution of the javascript function.

**The above problem canbe fixed in 2 ways:**

1. Make sure that the target element ***'agireceive'*** is defined before the javascript function executes.

or

2. As a best practice, include the javascript function at the bottom of the page. This will ensure that any javascript will load only after all the html elements are loaded. This will also improve the speed of page load.